# How can I make HttpServer recognise special characters in Java?

Tags: java, httpserver, simplehttpserver

I want to make some SQL query with my Java HttpServer but it seems that the HttpServer doesn't recognize special characters in the link I submit into my browser:

```
[1]: http://localhost:8001/test?query=SELECT * WHERE{ ?s rdf:type ?o. }
```

I always receive this response:

```
400 Bad Request
URISyntaxException thrown
```

This is the code for my server:

```
public class SimpleHttpServer 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{

        dir = args[0];
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8001), 0);
        server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null);
        server.start();
    }

    static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            String response ;
            System.out.println(t.getRequestURI().getQuery().toString().replaceAll("query=",   ""));
            response =   ExecuteHttpQuery.getInstance().httpQuery(t.getRequestURI().getQuery().toString().replaceAll("query=", "").toString(), dir) + "\n";
            t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes());
            os.close();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: you probably want to urlencode your link, since it contains spaces and other symbols. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Answer (score 5):

You should never pass your SQL Query in your URL.

Answer (score 5):

yes, there are certain characters which are not valid in certain parts of a url.  (*besides the fact that i hope you are just testing this and not actually using it for anything real, sql injection attacks and all*), you need to use URLEncoder to encode the sql query first.

Comment: i haven't foud how can i integrate the URLEncoder and Decoder with the HTTPServer
is there any example ?

Comment: @NabilCHOUAIEB - you would simply url encode the query on the client, and urldecode the query in the server.  which part isn't working?

Comment: the server part is not running , i want that the client be able to post URL like this http://localhost:8001/test?query=SELECT * WHERE{ ?s rdf:type ?o. } simply on his browser , and the server must be able to recognise all the characters have the request and post back the response what should i do exactly ?